# steam fails to start

Tags: kubuntu, steam

I have **Kubuntu 15.04** on **Linux work002 3.19.0-22-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 16 17:15:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux** kernel. When I try to run steam from terminal, I get following error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . Remove `libstdc++`:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_amd64 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_amd64.md5 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_amd64 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_amd64.md5 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.a && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.map && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6-4.6-pic && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_i386 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_i386.md5 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_i386 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_i386.md5 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.a && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.map && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6-4.6-pic && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6
```

2. Remove `libgcc_s`:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

> After that I was able to load up steam. Now because I tried a crapload
>   of things I don't know if doing this will really solve the problem, it
>   did for me, so hopefully it will for others.

3. Then run `updatedb` command try and locate any of these librarires again. (If you get command not found when running updatedb you need to install the mlocate package)
4. Finally, run:

`rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1`

**[SOURCE](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193802)**

Comment: it did not work either, same error persists.

Comment: Have you remove the mentioned file ?

Comment: Yes, but `upgdatedb` did not work, I had to run `sudo updatedb`. The error still persists.

Comment: Try launch steam use: `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 DIAPLAY=:0 steam` command

Comment: it seems to get running, now is updating!

Comment: Glad to hear that :D !

Answer (score 1):

I founded [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183659#4) workaround - not sure if it works

> As many of you know, Steam on GNU/Linux is coming with some bundled libraries in case the system does not have them, and some of the bundled libraries or drivers are outdated. As a workaround, just delete the files Steam says are broken; this will force Steam to use the system's libs and drivers.

Related to the post you can try (better do an backup before)

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

> You might have to do this two times, each time representing a different lib.

Comment: it did not work, same error persists.