# Steam won't run nor uninstall (Ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: steam, 16.10

Very similar to the problems in [I can neither open nor uninstall Steam (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795763/i-can-neither-open-nor-uninstall-steam-ubuntu-16-04-lts), I get this when i run "steam" in terminal:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/tom/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I tried the tips to delete the links to libgcc_s.so.1 and libstdc++.so.6, and to run the command as

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

to no avail.

Also, just tried

```
sudo apt-get install steam:i386
```

based on a small aside tip about 16.10 in a thread about 16.04, same errors after install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the solution found here - post #6:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cannot-start-steam/1677

---

```
find ~/.steam/root/ -name "libgpg-error.so*" -print -delete
```

Comment: Excellent! That allowed it to run and patch itself. Thank you very much.